# History auto complete in gnuplot

Tags: autocomplete, gnuplot, readline

In gnuplot, I type

```
gnuplot> set style data lines
```

Then I run few other lines:

```
gnuplot> plot "./data/traj1.dat" u 1:4, "" u 1:6, "" u 1:9, "" u 1:11, "" u 1:13, "" u 1:15
gnuplot> plot "./data/traj2.dat" u 1:4, "" u 1:6, "" u 1:9, "" u 1:11, "" u 1:13, "" u 1:15
gnuplot> plot "./data/traj3.dat" u 1:4, "" u 1:6, "" u 1:9, "" u 1:11, "" u 1:13, "" u 1:15
```

Now I want to change style. I start with

```
gnuplot> set
```

I want to press for example ctrl-r (http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts) and have the command be completed to

```
gnuplot> set style data lines
```

then I can change `lines` to `points` for example.

How do I make this auto-completion happen?

Comment: Have you tried to build gnuplot from source by using the ` --with-readline` option for the configure script. Search google for readline and gnuplot to get more information on that.

Comment: @psibar that would be my last option. i'd prefer using ubuntu's package

Answer (score 4):

A partial solution is indeed to compile gnuplot with readline support. You mention that this is your last option in the comments, but I think that it is your only option if not you want to code a gnuplot frontend yourself. Maybe it helps to know that it is really easy to compile gnuplot from the ubuntu sources. I just did this myself in <10 min. Simply run (in a directory of your choice) the commands

```
sudo apt-get purge gnuplot
sudo apt-get build-dep gnuplot
cd `mktemp -d`
apt-get source gnuplot
cd gnuplot*
./configure --with-readline=gnu
make
sudo make install
```

Pressing the tab-key after writing the first few letters will complete the present word and if you press tab twice it will print a list of suggestions as you know it from your gnu-shell. Unfortunately not all readline features seem to work with the current gnuplot (I know they did once). E.g. Ctrl+r for reverse search (would be very useful for gnuplot) does not work for me. Hope this helps though admittedly this is possibly only a partial solution for you.

Comment: Sure, if you like you can replace the last command with `checkinstall`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) to get this functionality (history search with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, filename and keyword completion) without compiling anything. If you use Ubuntu, install it from *universe* repositories by running:

```
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
```

Run gnuplot with:

```
rlwrap -a -N -c -b \' -D 2 -s 1000 gnuplot
```

where `-a -N` overrides gnuplot built-in readline support, `-c` gives you filename completion, `-b \'` lets you complete stuff like `plot 'incomp[TAB]lete'`, `-D 2` drops duplicates from history and `-s 1000` increases the history size from the default 300.

Or add this line to your start-up script (i.e., `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`), so you can use gnuplot without any additional typing:

```
alias gnuplot="rlwrap -a -N -c -b \' -D 2 -s 1000 gnuplot"
```

Also, it is possible to have keyword completion by listing all keywords in a file `$RLWRAP_HOME/gnuplot_completions`. However, context-sensitive completion is impossible using rlwrap.

You may want to export your gnuplot command history to rlwrap (so you don't have to start from scratch), like this:

```
tail -n +2 ~/.gnuplot_history | while read -r; do print $REPLY; done > $RLWRAP_HOME/gnuplot_history
```

`tail` gets rid of gnuplot's header and `print` converts escaped characters (I wonder why gnuplot's history is stored like this).

Comment: *Also, built-in filename completion is better than rlwrap's from what I've seen so far.* How could `rlwrap`'s filename completion be improved, according to you? (I'm rlwrap's author/maintainer)

Comment: @HansLub Thanks for answering, it seems rlwrap has a problem handling hyphens in filenames, I've just filed an [issue on github](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/37). Also it does not complete filenames when you write `plot 'incompl[TAB]`, maybe because that would make it context-sensitive, so I didn't include it in the report, but it is very typical usage in gnuplot, so I thought it is worth mentioning.

Comment: For an extended response see the [issue on github](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/37). Short answer: use `rlwrap` with `--break-chars=""` (or shorter: `-b ''`). This will make it consider whitespace as word-breaking, but not `-` and `'`

Comment: @HansLub thanks, I've edited my answer to reflect this