# Tab completion not working correctly in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, tab-completion

I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 and installed gnuplot only to find that something has gone terribly wrong with tab completion. What is actually happening is something like this: Say I have two files in the folder:

```
abc.dat
def.dat
```

Now, if I type the following in gnuplot:

```
plot 'a'
```

and press TAB, it doesn't complete the filename abc.dat; instead what I see on screen is this:

```
plot 'adef.dat'
```

I checked other questions related to tab completion but none of the solutions are working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24408177/2604213 for an explanation, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33009764/2604213 for a possible workaround with `rlwrap`

Comment: rlwrap worked. Thanks

Comment: Great. Did the link to the rlwrap answer help you? Then I would make your question a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Please do that if you think that it can be treated as the duplicate of that question. I don't directly see this and I am actually talking about slightly different issue. The solution rlwrap nevertheless works for both.  I added a following line to my .bashrc file to solve this issue: alias gnuplot="rlwrap -a -N -c -b \' -D 2 -s 1000 gnuplot"

Comment: Yes, you are right. That isn't a duplicate. Could you please add your solution as answer? Thanks!